# How can one iterate through Ruby GetoptLong object twice?

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments

Kindly look at this simple code, named foo.rb:

```
require( 'getoptlong' )
opts = GetoptLong.new(  [ '--ies', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ] )
opts.each do | opt, arg |
  if( opt == '--ies' )
    puts arg
  end
end
opts.each do | opt, arg |
  if( opt == '--ies' )
    puts arg
  end
end
```

I expect that if I input in LINUX:

```
foo.rb --ies=bar
```

I would get:

```
bar
bar
```

However, I get only 1 line:

```
bar
```

Why Can't I iterate twice through the GetoptLong instance?
Thanks,

Comment: I'd recommend [OptionParser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/index.html). It's a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation doesn't allow it. `GetoptLong#each` calls [`GetoptLong#get_option`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/getoptlong/rdoc/GetoptLong.html#method-i-get_option) in a loop until it returns `nil`, i.e. "the processing is complete". Once completed, it always returns `nil` and thus cannot be processed again.

You could create an array:

```
opts_array = []
opts.each { |o, a| opts_array << [o, a] }

opts_array.each do |opt, arg|
  # ...
end
opts_array.each do |opt, arg|
  # ...
end
```